# User based authorisation not working ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

Dear Senior Members of StackExchange

I am trying to give a user based authorisation to certain urls.
I have configured the web.config at the root as below

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms
      name="MyAuth"
      loginUrl="ABC/Login.aspx"
      protection="All"
      path="/"
    />
</authentication>
```

another web.config at the ABC Directory as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

every thing is working fine except the login
when I access the directory ABC login page is displayed even after giving correct username and password the page is redirected to login page itself.

I am new to C# and ASP.net

Please help me
my Code at aspx.cs is as below

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {

        string selectString = "SELECT * FROM users " + "WHERE Username = '" + Login1.UserName + "' AND Password = '" + Login1.Password + "'";

        MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(selectString,con);
        con.Open();
        String strResult = String.Empty;
        strResult = mySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        con.Close();

        if (strResult.Length > 0)
        {
            e.Authenticated = true;
            Response.Redirect("up.aspx");
        }

        else
        {
            MsgBox("Wrong username or password!.", this.Page, this);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Please help me
Thank You
Santosh Sharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code use the following instead :

```
 if (strResult.Length > 0)
    {
       FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage 
         (Login1.UserName, true);
        Response.Redirect("up.aspx");
    }
```